# XQuery: Separate a sequence into multiple ones

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I want to seperate a sequence into multiple ones.

So e.g. I have this sequence

```
let $allNumbers := (1,2,3,4,5)
```

And I want as an result one sequence with all number  less than 3 and one sequence with equal or more than 3.

```
let $lessThanThree := (1,2)
let $moreEqalThree := (3,4,5)
```

How would one best achieve this? The isse use, that you can not return multiple values from a FLWOR expression.

I am currently aware of multiple ways to do this, but all of them do not seem like a good solution. Keep in mind that I am currently Using MarkLogic 10 with the dialect

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
```

### Using multiple maps

You could loop over the sequence and the simply at the different element with `map:put()`. But this seems kind of wrong since we are not actually storing any Key-value-pairs.

### Using `xdmp:set()`

With xdmp:set() you could modify multiple variables, but this feels like kind of bad practice and not a function you should use. But maybe I am wrong here?

### Executing the FLWOR multiple times

This is an obvious solution however the issue is that sometime the loop may need quite a bit of time. Ff one loop takes 10 minutes I do not really want to execute it multiple times.

Comment: Why is `let $allNumbers := (1,2,3,4,5), lessThanThree := $allNumbers[. lt 3], $moreEqalThree := $allNumbers[. ge 3]` not possible? Does ML XQuery have arrays of sequences (if the task is to have a single variable/value then in XQuery 3.1 I would consider an array of sequences)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Its is, but this is more of a simple example. In my current issue I basically load a few documents, loop over them, extract some values and do some further stuff with these like searching through other documents of my database.
During that in a different language like in Java I would simply add one document to one List and one to another. However in XQuery this is not that simple and I am struggling with finding a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want the result of the query to be "two sequences". Well, the result of a query is always an XDM value, so you'll have to think about what kind of XDM value can hold two sequences. In 3.1 that's easy - use an array, so you're returning `[(1,2), (3,4,5)]`, and you could get that with the query

```
[$in[. le 3], $in[. ge 3]]
```

Before maps and arrays were introduced you would need to find some other representation, for example XML.

As regards performance, the devil is always in the detail. What form does the actual input sequence take, how is it computed? Normally I wouldn't expect that processing a sequence twice takes any longer than processing it once and doing twice as much work with each item. But it depends. And where is the output going?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess there is no real easy good answer, except for arrays which are not available for me. 
The issue why it is taking longer if you do it multiple times is, that very often I perform databaseoperations. I guess you can  write it, so you can reuse results, but there is probably no real common easy solution I am missing, which I guess answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, applying a predicate filter `$allNumbers[. lt 3]` and `$allNumbers[. ge 3]`, as Marting Honnen suggested, would be the most straightforward and natural way of doing things.

There are sometimes cases in which the sequence is really large or is otherwise an expensive operation and you want to minimize the number of times that a sequence is processed and iterated over.

For that, as you suggested in your question, you could look to use `xdmp:set()` or putting items into a `map:map` (or different maps).

But if it's taking 10 minutes to iterate over the set, you might want to take a step back and see if you are doing something "the hard way" with brute force, where you might instead be able to leverage indexes to get facets, ranges, frequency, etc. or to run a batch process instead of trying to do it all in one query. A "boil the ocean" type query won't be fast, even if you optimize some of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you brought the map option up:

```
fold-left($seq, map{ "lt3": [], "other": [] }, function ($res, $next) {
  if ($next < 3) then map:put($res, "lt3", array:append($res?lt3, $next))
  else map:put($res, "other", array:append($res?other, $next))
})
```

see it in action here https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6yn/1